# How to make this more efficient?

Tags: java, android, oop

I am creating an Asteroids clone, but with a few more bells and whistles.

As of right now I have an `ArrayList<Asteroid>` that holds all of the asteroids on screen. Each one has a `Vector` associated with it and extends my genereic `GameObject` class which handles the drawing and updating and other common things that each game object has in common.

That being said each time I destroy an asteroid I create a new `Asteroid` object and add it to the `ArrayList<Asteroid>`... There is a noticeable lag when this happens as I also create explosion particles and I assume this is the GC.

My idea was to instead of create new objects on the fly, that I can pre-create a pool of them and just re-use them.

Is this the right idea? Also what is the most organized and efficient way to go about that?

Any other ideas would be great as well. Just trying to reduce creating of all of these objects because it is definitely causing a noticeable lag. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tryed to find out what takes time with DDMS?

Comment: My guess is the delay is caused by your code waiting for the explosion to finish occuring before creating a new asteroid object. Try making the exploding asteroid animation asynchronous?

Comment: @dan: I haven't done this, though I think it will help. I don't use DDMS much, how can I use it for seeing what takes the longest?

Comment: @deed02392: I don't think that is the problem because on each render call, I check if a hit was detected, then if so I create 50 particles for the explosion and then I just update their positions along with everything else...

Comment: But the creation of the particles blocks subsequent frame renders right?

Comment: Profiling Methods with DDMS: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html - (Section: "Starting method profiling")Basically you start recording the Application and play arround with it. When you're finished you get a detailled Overview about invoked methods on a timeline.

Comment: I think you are right, maybe I should make the creation of the particles in a separate thread... I'll give it a try and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @dan: Thanks! I will do that, I really should've known about that by now haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a pool of objects and reusing them is a good idea. Also I think you could switch from `ArrayList` to `Vector`, because Vectors are optimized for random indexation, which you'll do a lot when using a pool.

Since you say that each time you destroy an asteroid, you add a new one, it seems that you work with a constant number of asteroids. So you could create pool with a constant number of members.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely switch to a `Vector`. That is a great suggestion, and good to know for future projects.

Answer (score 5):

(1) Consider design your objects with a Flyweight pattern. It is a pattern commonly used for objects with repeating characteristics. A java code sample is available here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

(2) If you already know how many objects you will be using, then consider includes your object creation and some other initialization process into a loading page.

Comment: I think I am definitely going to move to pre-creating the objects that I need. You are right, since I do know the number I need to create then that should help. I will look into the Flyweight Pattern. I like the sounds of it.

Answer (score 4):

Usually Java is very good at both allocating new objects and  performing GC of objects that was recently created so I would not immediately assume that pooling will improve things a whole lot. Are you sure that you are not creating any other "garbage" that may cause full GC (the kind of GC that pause the program for extended periods of time)?

You can verify that it really is GC that is causing the problem you observe by enabling "verbose GC logging" (Google for this there are several command line arguments to the JVM that enable it with different level of detail)...

Comment: I don't believe that I am creating other "garbage" but I will take a good look through to be sure. Since I am on Android I can't use the standard JVM but I should be able to use DDMS for determining what the GC is up to.

Comment: I have not done any Android development so what I said may not hold with the Dalvik "JVM". When developing real time embedded systems (that I have done a lot in the past) pooling was a standard practise and taking it to the extreme (pre-allocating most frequently used objects) solved many real-time problems for me in those days. 
I would however suspect that it would be hard to make your game "allocation free" since the graphics libraries you are using most likely are allocating things dynamically...

Answer (score 4):

I reckon your **particle effects** are the culprit of the slowdown, not the object creation.

Game developers typically go to great lengths to make sure their graphics are fast, but make many performance compromises in scripting. This is for very good reason: The performance hit in creation and storage of game objects is in most cases insignificant in comparison with the hit from calculating their physics and drawing their graphics.

Try reducing the number and graphical complexity (particularly if they have ***transparency***; the effects of that very quickly stack up to insane) of your particles.

Comment: I think you are right on with the particles being a slowdown. I'm going to try creating them in a separate thread and see if that helps at all. They also do carry transparency so that might be something to think about as well.